# Image not rotating in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting my image to rotate. I have tried using the image rotate property in CSS but that doesn't seem to have don the trick. The elements above the image are floated elements. I'm not sure if they might be interfering with the image in some way.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#wrapper {
  background: #eee;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.float {
  align-content: center;
  margin: 2.5%;
  max-width: 20%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  max-width: 70%;
  image-orientation: 90deg;
}
```

```html
<h1>Postioning Practice</h1>
<h2>Using Floated Elements</h2>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="float">
    <h3>Position 1</h3>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="float">
    <h3>Position 2</h3>
    <p>.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="float">
    <h3>Position 3</h3>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="float">
    <h3>Position 4</h3>
    <p>.</p>
  </div>

  <a href="yingCake.jpeg">
    <img src="yingCake.jpeg" alt="Image of Ying eating cake">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use transform: rotate(90deg)?

Comment: [image-orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation) only works in Firefox. Use Transform (as @zsawaf said) instead

Comment: Oh great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit should go to @zsawaf, but to answer this question. Indicated in the comments image-orientation is only for firefox browsers.

Instead in your css file use:

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "transform: rotate()" instead of image-orientation;

So the css for your image should look like this;

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  max-width: 70%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>Postioning Practice</h1>
<h2>Using Floated Elements</h2>

<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="yingCake.jpeg">
    <img src="yingCake.jpeg" alt="Image of Ying eating cake">
  </a>
</div>
```

`image-orientation` is an experimental feature with limited browser support.